# . notaion vs. [] notation | Inserting into a Text Object

Tags: javascript

I kind of move between dot notation and bracket notation on the line of code noted below.  `JavaScript - The Good Parts` suggests using dot notation by default.

How can I update this code to use the dot notation.  Note that form_elements contains form input names as keys which are valid JavaScript identifiers ( they use alphanumeric characters only ).

According to `JavaScript - The Good Parts` this means they can be used with the dot notation.

```
Su.text = function (form_elements) {
    this.text_object = {};
    var key;
    for (key in form_elements) { //*u
        if (form_elements.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            this.text_object[form_elements[key].name] = form_elements[key].value; // this line
        }
    }
    return this;
};
```

Comment: If the property name is dynamically determined as an expression or the contents of a variable, you _have to_ use `[]` notation, and it's fine to do so.  Just avoid using `[]` when you know the literal name of the property and use it in code.

Comment: Is this considered dynamically generated.....`form_elements[key].value`

Comment: Yes it is dynamic, because `key` is a variable assigned in the `for-in` loop.

Comment: then by causality...so is this.text_object[form_elements[key].name]...correct?

Comment: yep that case is as well

Comment: It's too bad, I know. I love that book and learned a ton from it, but I always was wanting a little more depth.

Comment: Also when the name of the property is not valid because starts or contains illegal characters for identifiers. For example, you can't do element.@video but you can do element["@video"]

Comment: @Michael....`Definitive JavaScript` seems good...on its like 6th edition or so...it even has a section analyzing `The Good Parts`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bracket notation is for key names that are not known at compile-time, such as in your case. So you have to use it here.

```
 aaa.foo  // dot notation, name of the field is "foo"

 aaa[foo] // bracket notation, name of the field is stored in variable foo
```

The one you want to avoid is

```
aaa["foo"]  // just ugly, necessary only if the field name is complicated

aaa["space and 123 in there"]   // like here
```

Comment: Yup, this is correct. I use the brackets when I am passing a dynamic key.